# Detect data flowing through a port in a bash script

Tags: linux, shell, timeout

I have data flowing through a Linux box and a custom command that prints the data as it flows to STDOUT (the screen). I want to detect if data is flowing and restart some processes if it's not.

Let's say my test file is "flowchk.sh". How do I use that in a conditional statement in a shell script? My plan so far has been to push the data to a file then check to see if the file has any data in it:

```
timeout 5s flowchk.sh > anythinghere
FILENAME=./anythinghere
MAXSIZE=5000
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s FILENAME)

if (( FILESIZE > MAXSIZE )); then
    echo "all ok"
else
    restarteverything!
fi
```

This has run into problems because the timeout command doesn't terminate properly when using my flowchk script (never returns to the command prompt). So I either need help figuring out how to stop flowchk's execution after a period of time (or it will run forever) so I can test the temp file to see if there's anything there OR I need to know if there's a better way to approach this problem and I'm wasting time.

Comment: What kind of port is the data flowing through?

Comment: What do you mean? It's a custom port number; let's say it was 15000.

Comment: OK so, tcp? udp? You might've meant it's flowing through a serial port